# Prevent sudo users switching to another user, without the target-users password?

Tags: sudo, password, su

Sorry if the title is ambiguous, however I'm quite new to Ubuntu but have just set up a webserver running it with a group "developers" that are all sudo.

At the moment Users can only login via SSH with a key tied to their account. But user1 could simply do:

```
sudo su - user2
```

And act as user2 without a password. Is there a way to force the same behaviour as

```
su - user2
```

which will actually require user2's password? Otherwise tracking each users commands to see who's done what is somewhat pointless..

Thanks!

Comment: There may be other methods to disable this ability to become another user, but the only thing I can think of is to define a group which you add the developers to. This group could be added to the sudoers file with sudo access only for a defined list of commands, which don't include `su`.

Comment: I'm not trying to disable it, but prompt for the targetUser's password when doing so

Comment: OK, I've retracted the duplicate vote.

Comment: Why do developers need sudo in your environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent switching users by `sudo su -`, you need to disable root's ability to `su` to any user. Edit `/etc/pam.d/su` and comment this line:

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

As the comment above this in `/etc/pam.d/su` says, this allows root to `su` without passwords.

Or you could restrict `sudo` usage to a limited set of commands which don't include `su` and force user-switching via `sudo -i -u`/`sudo -s -u`, and enable the `targetpw` option in `sudoers`.

Comment: Note that the user could still edit /etc/pam.d/su using sudo, and then sudo su

Answer (score 0):

Sudo privileges should only be given to those who may need to administer the machine itself. Other privileges can be managed through groups and group privileges. For instance, add user named 'developer1' to the www-data group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data developer1
```

This will add 'developer1' to Apache's www-data group.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
```

Will make sure that all files and directories in /var/www belong to group 'www-data'.

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

Will make sure that the group has write access to all files in /var/www

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group-www-data/